# Запрос на выборку из БД по промежутку времени в MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, access, oledb

Допустим, в базе данных есть таблица TABLE_NAME со столбцом DATE, содержащим дату.

Как должны выглядеть запросы на выборку:

1. Все записи со значением DATE - 10.07.2015.
2. Все записи со значениями DATE в диапазоне от 1.07.2015 до 10.07.2015.

Имею в виду `SelectCommand`:

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ...

Возьмём для примера такую таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание]

1. Запрос по дню = 03.03.2015. Должен выдать 2 запись.
2. Запрос по периоду = 01.11.2014 - 01.04.2015. Должен выдать записи 2-4.

Мне нужно внести результат в `DataSet`, но с этим проблем нет. Нужен только правильный запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так устроит:

```
-- Данный запрос вернет все записи со значением Created='10.07.2015'
select * from table where created = '10.07.2015'
--следующие запросы вернут записи в которых Created в диапазоне от 01 по 10
select * from table where created beetwen '01.07.2015' and '10.07.2015'
select * from table where created >='01.07.2015' and created <='10.07.2015'
```

**UPD** если это не то что Вам требуется то приведите пример данных и что хотите получить в результате запроса

**UPD2** попробуйте такую конструкцию

```
select * from table where created=#03.03.2015#11
select * from table where created Beetwen #01.11.2014# and #01.04.2015#
```

у самого Accessa нет установленного, но [источник](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU) утверждает что должно работать

Comment: Нет, имею в виду не созданы, а чтобы учитывались значения столбца DATE.

Comment: не понял тогда вопроса, перефразируйте, напишите пример данных и что надо получить тогда

Comment: написал немного конкретнее.

Comment: @InfernumDeus обновил ответ.

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: Составил по аналогии: SELECT * FROM Больные WHERE [Год рождения]='06.06.2015'. При выполнении получаю ошибку: ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса: [Год рождения]='03.03.2015'больные'.

Comment: @InfernumDeus обновил ответ. Думаю сейчас вопрос должен решиться положительно